# localhost vs 127.0.0.1 in iPhone 4 device

Tags: iphone, ios, localhost, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

Is there any difference if we use "http://localhost:7001" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:7001" in `NSMutableURLRequest`/`NSURLRequest` while using an iPhone 4 device?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:7001/"]
                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                timeoutInterval:60] autorelease];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` requires a DNS lookup. I presume iOS is smart enough to handle that lookup without consulting an external DNS server, but even so it takes some time. (And as @BoA notes, the lookup behavior can be locally reconfigured, though you shouldn't have to worry about that on non-jailbroken devices.)

If you're explicitly connecting to the local device, `127.0.0.1` should be faster and more reliable.

Comment: On the other hand, `localhost` is more future-proof than `127.0.0.1`, because it supports IPv6 loopback addresses... That will become really important once IPv4 support is dropped from iOS, around the time the iPhone 4,004 comes out.:-)

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` is securer than `localhost` as hackers can redirect `localhost` to an external IP through your hosts file like this:

```
 133.713.371.337     localhost
```

Comment: As @rickster pointed out, unless your target device is jailbroken, redirecting localhost shouldn't be a problem. If you're targeting jailbroken devices, all bets are off anyhow.